# mysql(Innodb) multiple processes get one record each time and update

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing a program which runs on multiple machine concurrently. These processes share the same database. Each process get a record from contents table where status=1, then update status=2 and deal with this record.

To avoid the conflict, I tried to lock the whole table, and then select a record, update status=2, and then release the lock. This ways, conflict can be avoided, but the operation seems cumbersome. It causes other problems (lock cannot be released if the process is killed before unlock).

Then I tried to use transaction.

```
set autocommit=0;
start transaction;
select * from contents where status=1 limit 1 for update;
update contents set status=2 where name=<content name from select query>;
commit;
set autocommit=1;
```

But it seems that locking a row cannot avoid the confliction.

Is there any better way to implement this kind of operation?

Comment: What is datatype of `status` column? What is allowed values list for it? Why you select all rows for update, not only one row which will be updated later?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to write "limit 1". The actual code includes "limit 1". I edited the post.

Comment: The datatype of status is INT, and allowd values are 0~9.

Comment: You use `WHERE name = <<name from query>>` in your `UPDATE` operation. Is your `name` column a primary or unique key? If not you may be UPDATEing more rows than you SELECTed. That might cause the problem you see. [Edit] your question to show us the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE contents` and we may be able to help you better.

Comment: Use specific reservation. Firstly:`UPDATE contents SET status = CONNECTION_ID() + 10 WHERE .. LIMIT 1` tries to reserve a row, then you process the row which have this status value (it will be unique over a table), and after processing you change the status to 2. If another process was reserved the same row concurrently then `SELECT * FROM contents WHERE status = CONNECTION_ID() + 10` will return no rows - in this case the process must operform another reservation attempt.

Comment: I used reservation and run test on it for about three days. I didn't get any error. Thanks.